# How to split server that has same name in Nginx

Tags: nginx, server, configuration, tls1.3

I'm new to Nginx.

I've created a web server that is listening port 443.

There are some locations. The main thing is that I wanna split those locations because that

It couldn't apply `$ssl_verify_client` options ( on / optional ) at once.

I know that only $ssl_verify_client options by `on` can handle with mutual TLS communications.
This is why I split it.

apply `optional` to url b, c

apply `on` to url only a

I've tried to run configurations like below

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  servername exam.com;
  ...
  ssl_verify_client on;
  ...
  locations /a {
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  servername exam.com;
  ...
  ssl_verify_client optional;
  ...
  locations /b {
  }
  locations /c {
  }
}
```

But It doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?
I think the server has a same servername

Answer (score 0):

In the `location block`, try writing:

```
ssl_verify_client optional;
```

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work. $ssl_verify_client options is not allow in locations block